# Trouble with Link List insert placement function in C.

Tags: c, linked-list

So here's the deal. I am probably way out of my competency on this (pretty new to C and programming in general). I'm getting segfault errors and the fn is not really doing what I need (as indicated by comments). I really appreciate any insight here. Gonna go read a bunch, was more or less following steps to get to this point, so I apologize for this, but I figure I get a line out there while I read up.

```
The idea is if input was:
1
2
3
4

Output should be:
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

Thanks in advance!

```
#include "orderedList.h"

Node *orderedInsert (Node * p, int newval)
/* Allocates a new Node with data value newval
   and inserts into the ordered list with 
   first node pointer p in such a way that the
   data values in the modified list are in 
   nondecreasing order as the list is traversed.
*/
{
if(p == NULL)
   {
      p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      p->data = newval;
      p->next = NULL;
      return p;
   }


Node * tmp = malloc(sizeof(Node));

  tmp->data = newval;

   while(p != NULL && p->data < tmp->data)
   {

    p = p->next;
   }

   p->data = tmp->data;
   p->next = NULL;
   return p;
}

void printList (Node * p)
/* Prints the data values in the list with 
   first node pointer p from first to last,
   with a space between successive values.
   Prints a newline at the end of the list.
*/
{
  while (p != NULL)
    {
      printf("%d \n", p->data);
      p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: why does this problem need a link list?

Comment: You are getting the error because p is NULL after the while loop. You need to reconfigure the while loop so p will not be NULL or handle the case when p is NULL.

Comment: @v3ga Because OP is learning about linked lists.

Comment: Is the prototype of `orderedInsert`fixed? How about giving us the header too?

Comment: Your printList outputs: `"1\n1\n2\n1\n2\n3\n"` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky. You could use a `Node**` (a pointer to a pointer to a Node) to keep track of the correct insert position.

This code should work:

```
Node *orderedInsert (Node * p, int newval)
/* Allocates a new Node with data value newval
   and inserts into the ordered list with 
   first node pointer p in such a way that the
   data values in the modified list are in 
   nondecreasing order as the list is traversed.
*/
{
   Node * tmp = malloc(sizeof(Node));   // will need a new node anyway, so put it first
   if(tmp == NULL)
       return 0;                        // no memory error

   tmp->data = newval;

   if(p == NULL || newval < p->data)    // this will also handle the case
   {                                    //   when the new node is the first
      tmp->next = p;
      return tmp;
   }

   Node** pp = &p->next;                // the pointer to pointer
                                        //   where the new node is inserted
   while((*pp) != NULL && (*pp)->data < tmp->data)
   {
     pp = &(*pp)->next;
   }
   tmp->next = *pp;      // *pp is the rest of the list that comes after new node
   *pp = tmp;            // now insert the new node
   return p;             // return the beginning of the list
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this goes a long way for my understanding! Truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
   while(p != NULL && p->data < tmp->data)
   {

    p = p->next;
   }
```

Imagine that p is equals to NULL

```
p->data = tmp->data;
```

are going to Segmentation fault

Plus, the insertion of your new Node is not correct, you have to change your algorithm.

What if you have to insert the node at the head of the list?

```
 p->data = tmp->data;
   p->next = NULL;
```

Are not going to make what you expect. Why? Think about it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
  while(p != NULL && p->data < tmp->data)
  { 
     p = p->next;
  }   
  p->data = tmp->data;
  p->next = NULL;
```

When the loop stops, either `p` is NULL, or `p->data >= tmp->data`. If `p` is `NULL`, these lines will attempt to dereference a null pointer:

```
  p->data = tmp->data;
  p->next = NULL;
```

And you never initialize `tmp->next`. In fact, you don't even insert `tmp` in the list, you are replacing the first value of `p` such that `p->data >= tmp->data` with `tmp->data` (which is `newval`). Not quite what you want.

You can't do it this way - you need to keep a reference to the node *before* the insertion point. Something like this (untested):

```
  if (p->data >= tmp->data) {
      /* Insert at beginning */
      tmp->next = p;
      return tmp;
  }
  Node *prev = p;
  p = p->next;

  while(p != NULL && p->data < tmp->data)
  {
     prev = p; 
     p = p->next;
  }   
  prev->next = tmp;
  tmp->next = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Node *orderedInsert (Node * p, int newval) {
/* Allocates a new Node with data value newval
   and inserts into the ordered list with 
   first node pointer p in such a way that the
   data values in the modified list are in 
   nondecreasing order as the list is traversed.
*/
    // Alloc and init the new node
    Node* new = malloc(sizeof new)
    new->data = newval;
    // Test for insertion at head
    if(!p or p->data >= newval) {
        new->next = p;
        return new;
    }
    // save head pointer for return
    Node* ret = p;
    // find the node after which we must insert
    while(p->next and p->next->data < newval)
        p = p->next;
    // insert node
    new->next = p->next;
    p->next = new;
    return ret;
}
```

Your `printList` didn't follow spec:

```
void printList (Node * p) {
/* Prints the data values in the list with 
    first node pointer p from first to last,
    with a space between successive values.
    Prints a newline at the end of the list.
*/
    if(!p) {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    for(;p->next;p = p->next)
        printf("%d ", p->data);
    printf("%d\n", p->data);
    return
}
```